# Z-scores and Probability

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, random-variable, expected-value

If $H$ is a normally distributed random variable with expected value 1.52 with standard deviation of 0.74.

What is the probability that p(H=1.52)?

Maybe I'm overthinking this but would you simply find the z-score for 1.52

$$P(x=1.52)= ( x-mean )/ STD\\ 
= (1.52 - 1.52 ) /0.74 \\ 
z=0 \\ 
p(x=1.52)=0.5000$$

Or would you have to do the following work $P (1.51 < x < 1.53)$?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The probability that H exactly equals 1.52 is 0, `P(H=1.52)=0`. Since the support for a continuous distribution is the real numbers, P(H=x)=0 for all x ∈ Real. What you might want to know is `P(H<1.52)=0.5`, which can also be written as `cdf(H, 1.52)` the value of the cumulative density function of H at 1.52.

You might also want to know the value of the [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) at a certain value.

In that case you can use the formula for a [Normal PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

```
julia> normpdf(x,μ,σ) = exp(-0.5*((x-μ)/σ)^2) / (σ*√(2π))
normpdf (generic function with 1 method)

julia> normpdf(1.52, 1.52, 0.74)
0.5391111897316658
```